# Unexpected output avoiding try/except

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, unix, pydev, gnome-terminal

I wrote this peace of code that is supposed to check whether the device is a RPI and output the temperature.

```
import os

def CheckIfPi():
    try:
        res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
        return float((res.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n","")))
    except:
        return 0

def ReturnTemperature():
    if CheckIfPi() > 0:
        print("The temperature of the Pi is: ", CheckIfPi())
    else:
        print("This is not a Pi.")


ReturnTemperature()
```

The output I get:

```
/bin/sh: 1: vcgencmd: not found
This is not a Pi.
```

The output i didnt expect to get was `/bin/sh: 1: vcgencmd: not found`